# How can I add a column to a postgres table in front of the others?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with lots of columns, and I'd like to add two more (date and time) to the front of the existing table.

There is no data in the table right now, but I'm wondering what the best way is get the table in the format I need it.

I could just drop the table and create a new one with the correct configuration, but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: Why does it have to be to the front of the existing table?  When you use a SELECT statement to pull the information you specify the order of fields then.

Comment: Two reasons: 1. I would like the select * behavior to show the most relevant columns first, and 2 I will be writing to the db with a script that organizes the information this way in a csv, and adjusting the script seems like a little more work than just adding a couple columns in front of the table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/how-do-i-alter-the-position-of-a-column-in-a-postgresql-database and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3276/how-can-i-specify-the-position-for-a-new-column-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. You have to drop and recreate the table.
Theoretically you could add the column, drop and re-add all other columns, but that's hardly practical.

It's an ongoing discussion and an open TODO-item of the Postgres project to allow reordering of columns. But a lot of dependencies and related considerations make that hard.

Quoting the [Postgres project's ToDo List:](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo)

> Allow column display reordering by recording a display, storage, and
>   permanent id for every column?

Contrary to what some believe, the order of columns in a table is **not irrelevant**, for multiple reasons.

- The default order is used for statements like `INSERT` without column definition lists.
  Or `SELECT *`, which returns columns in the predefined order.
- The composite *type* of the table uses the same order of columns.
- The order of columns is relevant for storage optimization (padding and alignment matter). More:

  - [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468)

People may be confusing this with the *order of rows*, which in undefined in a table.

Comment: Is there at least a way to get the schema for the table? like name, varchar(100) for each row so that I can reference that when rebuilding my giant table?

Comment: @johncorser: There are many ways. `\d tbl` in psql. Or use the reverse engineered CREATE scripts provided by pgAdmin ...

Comment: `SELECT *` is a bad practice which is not recommended. Same goes to insert without a list, or not using `order by` just because the incidental order whitout it suits your needs. An application should not fail because the order of columns in a table changed.

Comment: `SELECT *` and `INSERT` without target list are bad practice in certain contexts. Doesn't make the order of columns irrelevant, though. That's just a false claim.

Comment: I still don't get it why the order of columns is relevant if there is at least one column that has a variable length. Because then the "following" rows in a database block won't be aligned properly. Only the row that is physically located at the beginning of a block will benefit from the column order - until one of the columns gets longer (and stays below the TOAST limit)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: If the [example in the linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468) doesn't do the trick for you, I suggest you ask a question, so we can address this properly.

Comment: The example in the linked question only uses fixed length data types. I can somehow understand the alignment advantage there, but not if a row contains variable length columns. The alignment can't be working then.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: If you have a column that requires alignment (like `int`) after a column that doesn't (like `text`) or has different alignment needs (like `int2`), Postgres adds **padding** up to the next multiple of `n` bytes (if needed), to the next possible start address, thereby wasting space. More related answers [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570613/making-sense-of-postgres-row-sizes/13570853#13570853). This would make a very nice question ...

Answer (score 0):

- In relational databases the order of columns in a table is irrelevant
- Create a view that shows you the columns in the order you want
- If you still want to, drop the table and recreate it

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Not "order in tables" but "column order in tables"

Comment: Well, I have to disagree. Column order is well-defined and matters in multiple ways. I wrote more in my answer. It's irrelevant in set theory or relational algebra, but not in the Postgres implementation (or any other RDBMS implementation). Not even in standard SQL.