# Migration: add a column after a specific column

Tags: migration, knex.js

This is easy to do with SQL but I need to write a Knex migration script which I am not familiar with. The following adds the `order_id` column at the end of the row in the `order` table. I want `order_id` to be added after `id`. How do I do that?

```
const TABLE_NAME = 'order';
exports.up = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema.alterTable(TABLE_NAME, table => {
        table
            .specificType('order_id', 'char(10)')
            .unique()
            .notNullable();

    });
};

exports.down = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema.table(TABLE_NAME, function (t) {
        t.dropColumn('order_id');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Old topic, but I found a answer:

```
return knex.schema.table('the_table', table => {    
    table.tinyint('new_column').defaultTo('0').after('other_column')
})
```

This work on Mysql databases.

Comment: Link to official documentation: http://knexjs.org/#Schema-after

Answer (score 2):

There is no SQL that determines column order on altering a table. The order is determined on query so that, for example:

```
knex
  .select('id', 'order_id')
  .from('order')
```

yields

```
id | order_id
===+=========
1  | 2
```

whereas

```
knex
  .select('order_id', 'id')
  .from('order')
```

yields

```
order_id | id
=========+===
2        | 1
```

If an individual database engine did support changing the order of columns after table creation, that would be specific to that engine and not easy for a SQL generator like Knex to manipulate. See [How do I alter the position of a column in a PostgreSQL database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/how-do-i-alter-the-position-of-a-column-in-a-postgresql-database-table) for more.