# How to insert columns at a specific position in existing table (postgres)?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a existing table with some columns , my objective is to add a new column at the first position using postgres, how can i do this? Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this has already been (not) answered. Postgresql doesn't feel column order is significant.

[How to alter position of postgres columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/how-do-i-alter-the-position-of-a-column-in-a-postgresql-database-table#:%7E:text=%22Alter%20column%20position%22%20in%20the,you%20reach%20the%20desired%20layout.)

> "[Alter column position](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position)" in the PostgreSQL Wiki says:
>
> > PostgreSQL currently defines column order based on the attnum column
> > of the pg_attribute table. The only way to change column order is
> > either by recreating the table, or by adding columns and rotating data
> > until you reach the desired layout.

Comment: Rather than adding this link-only answer, you should have flagged the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. (Though I don't believe that I can flag as duplicate until I have a higher rank)