# How to insert column after specific column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Please suggest me how to put value in specific colum's row and also explain me where I'm wrong?

#sqlmembers

try to add value in one column in data set but it shows error

Comment: You can't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/how-do-i-alter-the-position-of-a-column-in-a-postgresql-database-table