# How to add column before or after existing column

Tags: postgresql

It looks to me that Postgresql deosn't support to add column before or after existing column, and it only adds the column as the last position. Often I need to add a column, but I don't want to add it at last, I have to drop the table and recreate the table, and insert the data that the table already has.

I would ask if there is an appoach to add a column at the desired position.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/285740). I'm curious about why you want it in a specific order.

Comment: View could be a good and fast solution for that.

Comment: @anupsabraham, good for you if you don't need this.

Comment: We have 4 columns, created_by, created_date, last_updated_by, last_updated_date.By convention, they are the last 4 columns, the other columns are business columns and before the 4 columns.

Comment: Why do you care? And Yes, you're right, it's not supported.

Comment: @FrankHeikens. OK, great.

Answer (score 2):

Use the CREATE TABLE statement to create a new table with the specified column order and the new column.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    new_column datatype,
    old_column1 datatype,
    old_column2 datatype
);
```

Copy data from the old table to the new table using INSERT INTO

```
INSERT INTO new_table (id, new_column, old_column1, old_column2)
SELECT id, new_column, old_column1, old_column2 FROM old_table;
```

Give the new table the name of the old table, and rename the old table to a temporary name.

```
ALTER TABLE old_table RENAME TO old_table_temp;
ALTER TABLE new_table RENAME TO old_table;
```

Comment: Thanks, currently, I am using this approach, which can' t be more ugly.