# How to change the column's position in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

If I have a table `User`.

At first, it has 2 columns `phone`, `address`

Later I need to a an new column `name`,

How could I add the new column and put the new column in first position.

I know how to add a new column

```
add_column :users, :name, :string
```

But not knowing how to change its order.

Because it will append to the last position by default.

I read a book  'head first SQL'

It told me , it's a better practice to put your primary key in the first position

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position

Why do you want to change columns position?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the natural order of columns in Postgres?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126430/is-it-possible-to-change-the-natural-order-of-columns-in-postgres)

Comment: I really wonder Why do you want to change columns position? just curious to know why??

Comment: @varchar hi I updated it

Comment: Your primary key by default (and by convention) is `id` and it is in first position.

Comment: So, you created a table without a primary key? I hope you are in an early development phase & I suggest you to just drop your table, think about your domain model again & recreate it, when you have finished designing your tables.

Comment: Code that relies on ordinal positions of columns is IMO broken code.

Comment: I often change a column's position after I add a new column - not for any technical reason, just because it makes it easier to understand the table when you look at it in the sql terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:first` option

```
add_column :users, :name, :string, :first => true
```

Comment: How is that supposed to work given that it's not possible at the SQL level?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:after` in rails to position your columns like this:

```
add_column :users, :name, :string, :after => :id #primary_key
```